# If a windows server 2012 gets an OS upgrade to windows server 2019 will all the WAS and HTTP server instances running on it get effected?

Tags: https, websphere, windows-server-2012, windows-server-2016, windows-server-2019

If a windows server 2012 gets a OS(Operating System) upgrade to windows server 2019 will all the WAS (WebSphere Application Server ) and HTTP server instances running on it get effected ?

I am very new to servers so this question may actually sound stupid. But please bear with me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, all instances of WAS and IHS will be affected.